# Show modules inside the content section

Tags: opencart, journal

I'm using OpenCart 2.0.3.1 and Journal v 2.4.8.
The issue is: when I add any module (slider, side categories menu etc.) and place it in the content section (content top, content bottom, columns etc.) it doesn't appear on my webpage. But when I tried to place my slider on "top" or "bottom" position, everything worked properly (slider appeared above/under my content section). Guess something doesn't work correctly with adding modules inside the content section.
Can you give me some ideas?

Comment: On which tpl file you wants to show that modules ?

Comment: @NipunTyagi, on my Home page.

Comment: then you have to check your home.tpl file & cross check that $content_top variable print in this template or not? .. I think you don't print those variable in home.tpl file that's why you're getting these issue.

Comment: @NipunTyagi "catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/home.tpl" is: <?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?><?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>

Comment: sorry for this ugly style :)